# Can a flying creature with Hover be knocked prone?

Tags: dnd-4e, prone, flight

If a creature is flying and has the `Hover` keyword, what happens to it when an attack power inflicts the `prone` condition on it?

(created to discuss the issue as raised in [Would flying monsters ever land during combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19793/would-flying-monsters-ever-land-during-combat) and [What can a player do to force down a flying creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19808/what-can-a-player-do-to-force-down-a-flying-creature))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It falls to the ground as normal**

The `Hover` keyword does not affect falling prone. As per the compendium entry for `Hover`:

> **Hover**: If a creature can hover, it can remain in the air if it is stunned.

Note that the compendium entry for `Stunned` specifically confirms this:

> **Stunned**: The creature falls if it is flying, unless it can hover.

Otherwise, it follows all the rules as normal for `Flying`:

> **Falling Prone**: If a creature is knocked prone while it is flying, it falls. This means a flying creature falls when it becomes unconscious or is subject to any other effect that knocks it prone. The creature isn’t actually prone until it lands and takes falling damage.

Note that the `Stunned` condition does not inherently cause a creature to be knocked prone, thus the special rule for flying creatures falling under the definition of Stunned, and the special counter to that rule in Hover.

Comment: Note that these represent errata from the original flight rules published in the Dungeon Master's Guide, which required creatures without hover to move 2 spaces in order to remain flying. However, even the original DMG flight rules caused hovering creatures to crash if knocked prone.